# iPhone: There is no SDK with the name or path 'iphoneos3.0'

Tags: iphone, xcode

A friend of mine just had to reinstall his OS (after power went down while updating) and when he installed Xcode he got this error.  In the drop down that usually has device/simulator etc, it said 'missing'.  I also noticed he had no developer folder on his machine as well. Anyone know why this might be?

Comment: He installed Xcode and got no /Developer directory? That sounds fishy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had him reinstall it with me there, and I noticed that the action for the developer tools, was install as opposed to upgrade, and it was grayed out so not sure how he would have been able to avoid that.  In any event he reinstalled and got the same error when launching from the dock.  He then launched from terminal and it worked fine... so somehow he got two installs or some weird scenario.  In any event we found the .app that spotlight saw and put it on the dock and then it worked.

Answer (score 7):

Tell me about it. Try this
in XCode goto 'Project' Menu and select 'Edit Project Settings'. In the General tab, last but one item, select the drop down list 'Base SDK for all Configuration' There you can specify which SDK your project will target.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem after installing the Xcode that comes with Snow Leopard. To solve it I downloaded Xcode for iPhone. The Xcode that comes with Snow Leopard does not include the iPhone SDK.You have to be a registered iPhone developed to use it.

Answer (score 0):

The system does not include the dev tools (and hence the /Developer folder) by default. He needs to re-install the dev-tools from his CD (or from developer.apple.com), and also re-install the iPhone SDK (only available on developer.apple.com).

EDIT: I didn't see he re-installed XCode. Sounds weird. Make sure you re-install everything, and that you have the correct rights. However, is no issue is found by the installer and you still don't have a /Developer directoty, there might be something weird going on...

Answer (score 0):

After Xcode updated to Version 11.6 got this error.

```
error: There is no SDK with the name or path '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.5.sdk'
```

Looks like iPhoneSimulator13.5.sdk got removed.

Fix by downloading "iOS 13.5 Simulator"

```
In Xcode -> Preferences -> Components downloaded iOS 13.5 Simulator again.
```